# Angular flashing when deleting entry

Tags: html, angularjs, postgresql, optimization

I made a MVC todo app using Express, Postgres, and Angular. However, whenever I delete one of the "todo's" the whole app flashes white momentarily as it updates the list of todo's. When I look at todomvc.com's example of the angular todo it has no flashing. Anyone have any idea on how I can eliminate the flashing?

Here is my delete method

```
$scope.deleteTodo = function(todoID) {
  $http["delete"]('/todos/' + todoID).success(function(data) {
      $scope.todoData = data;
      console.log(data);
      $http.get('/todos').success(function(data) {
        $scope.todoData = data;
        console.log(data);
      }).error(function(error) {
        console.log('error');
      });
    }).error(function(data) {
      console.log('error');
    });
 };
```

Comment: Why do you assign the return value to `$scope.todoData` and then reassign it in the next callback? (You should also use promises instead of callbacks)

Comment: @gr3g sorry, I'm new to web dev and I'm not sure what promises are, I'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.deleteTodo = function(todoID) {
  $http["delete"]('/todos/' + todoID).success(function(data) {
      $http.get('/todos').success(function(data) {
        $scope.todoData = data;
      }).error(function(error) {
        console.log('error');
      });
    }).error(function(data) {
      console.log('error');
    });
 };
```

*Better way*

```
   var self = this;
   self.deleteTodo = function(todoID) {
      $http.delete('/todos/' + todoID)
           .then(function(val){
                return $http.get('/todos');
            })
            .then(function(result){
               self.todoData = result;
            }, function(error){
                 console.log("ERROR", error);
            });
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and readers need to understand how it once worked.